# Where does the org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.jar file go

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.5. I try to compile a project and get:

ould not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.0

I found the jar file in the mvnrepository and downloaded it. I now need to know which directory to put the jar file in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all occurrences of mavenCentral() with jcenter() in the gradle build

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```